# CF/jQuery Adding to Database and refreshing into Select

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am making a single page application using ColdFusion and jQuery. I am trying to figure out how to add a new dealer with my "New" button that opens up a modal asking for new dealer name.. upon accept I would like to update the database with the next available "ID" adding the dealer and somehow have the name then show up in the dealer dropdown by refreshing. At the moment I have a dealer dropdown that fills from a database calling a cfc like so:

index.cfm

```
    <cfset cfcDealerTracking = new dealerTracking()>
    <cfset dealerListing = cfcDealerTracking.allDealers()>

<div class="col-xs-12">
   <label for="Dealers"></label>
   <div class="input-group">
     <select name="Dealers" id="Dealers" class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected></option>
        <cfoutput query="dealerListing">
          <option value="#Name#">#Name#</option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select> <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NewDealer"><u>N</u>EW</button>
                            </span>

     </div>
</div>
```

dealerTracking.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="allDealers" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var getDealers = ''>
    <cfquery name="getDealers">
        SELECT Name
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
        ORDER BY Name
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn getDealers>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbr4wb5f/7/

what I have tried:

Added line in index.cfm (under `<cfset dealerListing = cfcDealerTracking.allDealers()>`).

```
<cfset addedDealer = cfcDealerTracking.insertAddedDealer()>
```

Added Function to cfc:

```
<cffunction name="insertAddedDealer" access="public" returntype="boolean">
    <cfset var newDealerAdd = ''>
    <cfquery name="newDealerAdd">
        INSERT INTO dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers (Name)
        VALUES (#form.NewDealerName#)
    </cfquery>
  <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

AJAX Calling to Set Variable (NewDealerSession.cfm):

```
<cfset session.dealerwork.newdealername = form.NewDealerName >
    <cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.dealerwork.newdealername)#</Cfoutput>
```

Comment: The modal is gonna post to the index.cfm? If so and if you want the new value to appear in the listing, the line where you add should be before the line where you lists the values. It is a bit confusing your question.

Comment: Well its a single page application, so the the dropdown next to the new button already populates when you open. I want the new button when clicked to open the modal then enter the new dealer name. When accept is chosen it will submit to the database then refresh index.cfm page so that it will appear in the dropdown next to the "NEW" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 8 years ago I did something similar.  I used 3 files, which I'll call Page1.cfm, page2.cfm and Page3.cfm.

Page1.cfm had the main form, with the ability for the user to add records on the fly.  It included this javascript code:

```
function ServiceOther() {
if (document.someForm.someSelect.value == "OTHER" ) {

NewContact=window.showModalDialog("Page2.cfm?someUrlVariables, etc");

if (NewContact == true) // return value from dialogue
window.location="Page1.cfm?urlvariables";

} // end if
}// end of function
```

Page2.cfm included this:

```
<cfform name="someForm" 
Action="Page3.cfm" 
method="post" 
onsubmit="window.returnValue = true; window.close();">
```

Page3.cfm had the code to process the form from Page2.cfm, add the record, and also had:

```
<script language=javascript>
function CloseWindow() {
window.open('','_self','');
window.opener = top;
window.close();
}
</script>
```

and finished with

```
<body onload="window.returnValue = true;  CloseWindow();">
</body>
</html>
```

There may be better ways available, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add an onClose() function to your modal that calls an update function in your main page ( window.top.updateDropDownFunction() )that refreshes the drop down from an ajax call.

Comment: any chance for an example I am very new to this Ajax stuff